# How do you make two divs go next to eachother without using positioning?

Tags: html, positioning, line

I was writing a code for my new website but when i make two divs which should be next to eachother, one goes under the other. I have tried positioning like this:

```css
    position: absolute; top:20px; left:20px;
```

but on certian browsers everything gets jumbled up. Here is my code, and i am trying to get 'left' at the left with 'main' to the right of it.

```
    <div  id="left" style="background-image:url(bg2.png); width: 326px; position: relative; z-index: -10;" ><img src="aldesign.png">
    <br>
    <img src="home.png" onmouseover="this.src='home2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='home.png'" />
    <br>
    <img src="about.png" onmouseover="this.src='about2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='about.png'" />
    <br>
    <img src="contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='contact2.png'"onmouseout="this.src='contact.png'" />
    <br>
    <br></div><div id="main" style="background-image:url('bg3.png');  background-repeat:repeat; width:924px; height: 522px; float: right;">
    </div>
```

Please help as soon as possible! Thanks :)

Comment: divs automatically take up the full width of their container, unless you float them and fix a width. why not try spans instead for this sort of thing?

Comment: Thanks, i just had to float 'left' left and 'main' right. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%">
   <div id="left" style="float:left; width:50%">
   </div>
   <div id="right" style="float:left; width:50%">
   </div>
</div>
```

this will keep both divs adjacent to each other.